# VSCode snippet for C, C++ include headers

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am trying to create a snippet in VSCode that will generate a template when I type `inc`.

The template should be either:

`#include "header-file"`, or `#include <header-file>`

based on the selected brackets.

Additionally, the cursor should be placed inside the brackets.
For example, if I select angle brackets, the generated template should be `#include <cursor>`.

This is what I have tried so far:

```json
{
    "Include Header": {
        "scope": "c,cpp",
        "prefix": "inc",
        "body": "#include ${1|\"$0\",<$0>|}",
    }
}
```

However, the result is not what I expected. VSCode is treating $0 as a string literal, and the output is either `#include <$0>` or `#include "$0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this snippet

```json
  "Include Header": {
    "scope": "c,cpp",
    "prefix": "inc",
    "body": "#include ${1|\",<|}${2:header}${1/</>/}",
  }
```

If you have typed the header file (`$2`) and press TAB you are at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
"Include Header": {
    "scope": "c,cpp",
    "prefix": "inc",
    "body": "#include ${1|\"<\",\\\"|}${2:header-file}${1|\\\">\",\\\"|}",
    "description": "Include a header file"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information?

Comment: Yeah, this is the initial state (after the snippet turned on):
the output can be (literally): 
#include "<"header-file"<" 
or 
#include \"header-file\"

the inner header though can be modified. but the surrounding brackets are incorrect.